# Switch VM on for HTTP request and then auto switch off?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any service that will switch my VM on for an HTTP request and then switch it off after a period of no requests?

I have a low traffic service that seems a waste to keep on all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your system to a serverless architecture, using AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda. Then there would be nothing running at all until a request comes in, and you would only be billed for the time it takes to process requests.

Another option is to containerize your application and use [AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/), which has the ability to place your container in a "hibernate" type of state where you are only charged for memory usage (not CPU usage) if there are no requests coming in. This feature has not been rolled out to other AWS container orchestration services yet.

There is no option for doing what you want with a VM, because a VM takes too long to start up so it wouldn't be able to respond to an HTTP request in a reasonable time. You will have to look into modifying your application in some way in order to take advantage of "scale to 0" options within AWS.